# xcode map view return nil fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, viewcontroller

I am trying to add new annotation to my mapView after user receive push notification. But this always return fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Please note that I have used the same code else where in the project (in the same view controller to be precise) without error. and I also printed out the values so I am sure the problem is with the view controller.

When user receive push notification, I call a method from the view controller to from app delegate didreceiveRemoteNotification to process the notification. The method get called successfully and the data was passed correctly but the app always crash when its time to add annotation.

Here is what I have tried; 
I tried to declare annotation locally within this method that was called by the app delegate but still that wont work.

any help please

here are the codes Appdelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }



        // Create a pointer to the Photo object
    if let objectID: String = userInfo["extractThis"] as? String{
        println(objectID)

        //let rootViewController = ViewController.self
        //rootViewController.appDelegateCall(objectID as! AnyObject)
        println("I am calling the method in viewcontroller")
        var vc = ViewController()
        vc.appDelegateCall(objectID)

    }


}
```

and the view controller method that was called from AppDelegate

```
func appDelegateCall(abbey : String){

    println("I was called by the Appdelegate with value \(abbey)")
    var query = PFQuery(className:"drops")
    println("break point")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(abbey) {
        (newDrop: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        println("break point 2 with abbey as \(abbey)")
        if error != nil {
            println("no object found for \(abbey)")
        }

        else if let object = newDrop {

            var wrapstatus: AnyObject! = object.objectForKey("status")
            var status: String = wrapstatus as! String
            var objectID = object.objectId!
            var bar: AnyObject! = object.objectForKey("latitude")
            let noteLat = (bar as! NSString).doubleValue
            var bar2: AnyObject! = object.objectForKey("longitude")
            let noteLong = (bar2 as! NSString).doubleValue
            var dropperName: AnyObject! = object.objectForKey("dropper")
            var dropTime: AnyObject! = object.objectForKey("when")
            var dropedNote: AnyObject! = object.objectForKey("note")
            var receiver: AnyObject! = object.objectForKey("receiver")
            var latitude:CLLocationDegrees = noteLat
            var longitude:CLLocationDegrees = noteLong
            let noteLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(noteLat, noteLong)
            var locationP = CLLocation(latitude:noteLat, longitude:noteLong)


            //add coordinates to array
            MyVariables.noteLocation += [locationP]

            var newNote = CustomPointAnnotation()
            newNote.coordinate = noteLocation
            newNote.title = "\(dropperName)"
            newNote.subtitle = "\(dropTime!) \n from: \(dropperName) \n \(dropedNote) \n\(objectID)\n\(status)"

            if status == "unread"{

                newNote.imageName = "cNote.png"
            }

            else{

               newNote.imageName = "ownNote.png"
            }

           // the app always crash here
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(newNote)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: var vc = ViewController(), this will create a new class object. You need to use the existing one.

Comment: No, that is not the problem, my viewController name is simply ViewController and I used var vc to refer to it even when I tried your suggestion by deleting that line and using ViewController().appDelegateCall(objectID)  directly , the app still crash

Comment: ViewController().appDelegateCall(objectID)  is also wrong.You are not supposed to call this way.

Comment: @Amit89 please tell me how to call

Comment: between Xcode doesn't throw any error when I call the method either of the ways .... the method actually get called but I don't seem to be able to do anything with the map.